# Round down to nearest of Multiple of N

Tags: sql, postgresql, rounding

I have sql table as follows

```
+-----------------------------+
| |col1 |  col2 | col3| col4| |
+-----------------------------+
| _______________________     |
| | a | 3   | d1 | 10 |       |
| | a | 6   | d2 | 15 |       |
| | b | 2   | d2 | 8  |       |
| | b | 30  | d1 | 50 |       |
+-----------------------------+
```

I would like transform the above table into below, where the transformation is
`col4 = col4 - (col4 % min(col2) group by col1)`

```
+------------------------------+
| |col1 |  col2 | col3| col4|  |
+------------------------------+
| ____________________________ |
| |a | 3   | d1 | 9  |         |
| |a | 6   | d2 | 15 |         |
| |b | 2   | d2 | 8  |         |
| |b | 30  | d1 | 50 |         |
|                              |
+------------------------------+
```

I could read the above table in application code to do transformation manually, was wondering if it was possible to offload the transformation to sql

Comment: Please don't replace text with images. Text makes it far easier to create a test case to answer the question.

Comment: @nick i tried to use https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ for ascii text table , but it was being rendered as a single line, thanks for the format

Comment: You just needed to format it as code. That's all I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run a simple `select` query for this:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       col4 - (col4 % min(col2) over (partition by col1))
from t;
```

There is no need to actually modify the table.

Comment: Would it be possible to get min value of new col4 ( say col5) for unique combination of col1,col3 , query " select col1 ,col3 , 
      min(col4 - (col4 % min(col2) over (partition by col1))) as col5
from table1 group by col1,col3; " results in "Query Error: error: aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls" ?

Comment: @Ganesh . . . I think you need a subquery and two window functions for that.  However, if that doesn't solve your problem, ask a new question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, figured out the query " select col1,col3,min(col5) from ( select col1 ,col3 , 
      col4 - (col4 % min(col2) over (partition by col1)) as col5
from table1 ) as t2 group by col1,col3 order by col1,col3; "

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multi-table `UPDATE` to achieve your desired result, joining your table to a table of `MIN(col2)` values:

```
UPDATE table1
SET col4 = col4 - (col4 % t2.col2min)
FROM (SELECT col1, MIN(col2) AS col2min
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY col1) t2 
WHERE table1.col1 = t2.col1
```

Output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
a       3       d1      9
a       6       d2      15
b       2       d2      8
b       30      d1      50
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/56LRDoh6mHP5iMQBHpyEa3/0)